# How to add two separate fields and aggregate over that sum

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have some mock data for banks in elastic search which looks like this:

```
{
 "_index": "test_data",
 "_type": "test_type",
 "_id": "AVobMd1YHpQD-9cT3TmO",
 "_score": 1,
 "_source": {
 "bank_name": "BOFA",
 "transactions_sent": 79,
 "transactions_received": 27,     
 }
}
```

I want to be able to add the values of **transactions_sent** and **transactions_received** to get total transactions and then have an aggregation over total transactions. I'm using elasticsearch 2.4.

I kind of figured out the solution using the **script** query.

```
"sum":
  "script":{
    "inline": "doc['transactions_sent'].value+doc['transactions_received'].value"
  } 
}
```

The query time has increased by 8 times when I aggregated using the above query on the **inline** value compared to if I aggregate on either one of **transaction_sent** or **transactions_received**. Is there any other way to do it apart from the **script** query

Comment: Are you using Kibana for the visualization of the above?

Comment: No, I try my queries on the sense plugin of chrome, if thats what you were asking about visualization.